# Totally unexplainable NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net, exception, clr, nullreferenceexception

Ok, so I very sporadically get a NullReferenceException on this line of code:

```
if (!_oracleTenantSettings.OraclePlanSettings.ContainsKey(_key) || _oracleTenantSettings.OraclePlanSettings[_key] == null)
```

and/or this line:

```
_oraclePlanSettings = _oracleTenantSettings.OraclePlanSettings[_key];
```

where OraclePlanSettings is a SortedList, and it can't be null, because the code in question is surrounded by:

```
 if (_oracleTenantSettings.OraclePlanSettings != null && _oracleTenantSettings.OraclePlanSettings.Count > 0)
```

So I'm getting a NRE, but there is not a single part of the entire line of code that could ever possibly be null, ever. Period. (sense the frustration?) And that includes the key, but that wouldn't throw a NRE anyway. I do not understand. Is it possible that VS is just misplacing the CLR exception? If so, where would be a good place to start looking?

The stack trace is just a one-liner:

```
 at company.product.Mvc.OracleSettingsStoreCache.VerifyValueInCacheOrInsert[T](T& returnVal, SettingsType settingType, String tenantId, String planId, String pageMnemonic, String processId, String transcationType, String language, String country, String wapTransactionType, String wapCodeGroup, String wapLoanReasons, String palleteType, Boolean isInsert, Object _cacheValue) in blahblahblah.OracleSettingsStoreCache.cs:line 290
```

Here is the entire block of code:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tenantId) && (!IsWacMode() || (IsWacMode() && settingType == OracleSettingsType.SettingsType.FetchWAPInvestmentTransfer)) && _useCache != "false")
                {
                    tenantId = tenantId.ToUpper().Trim();

                    _oracleTenantSettings = null;

                    if (_oracleCacheManager.Contains(_cacheKey))
                        _oracleTenantSettings = _oracleCacheManager.Get<OracleTenantSetting>(_cacheKey);

                    if (_oracleTenantSettings != null)
                    {
                        if (_oracleTenantSettings.OraclePlanSettings != null && _oracleTenantSettings.OraclePlanSettings.Count > 0)
                        {
                            _key = language + "_" + country + "_" + tenantId;
           ***LINE 290***   if (!_oracleTenantSettings.OraclePlanSettings.ContainsKey(_key) || _oracleTenantSettings.OraclePlanSettings[_key] == null)
                            {
                                _objectMissing = TypeOfObjectMissing.TenantObjectDoesNotExist;
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Have you looked at in the debugger to see *exactly* what is throwing the NRE?  It possible that the exception is occurring inside of the `OraclePlanSettings` property getter and it's just being surfaced in your code.

Comment: Are you sure that's the line of code of the actual exception?  Or is it the first line of *user* code in the stacktrace?

Comment: _key = language + "_" + country + "_" + tenantId; where all three of those are input arguments to the method that contains all this code. so if that were ever the issue, it'd blow up on the method call

Comment: @CodingGorilla thats what I thought, except it couldnt be, because: 

public SortedList<string, OraclePlanSettings> OraclePlanSettings { get; set; }

Comment: Can you include the stack trace?

Comment: I'd add the stack trace, but its really company-specific and itd take me forever to clean up

Comment: hang on, actually, ill just "find and replace all" some stuff

Comment: What about `_oracleTenantSettings`? Are you sure that's not null?

Comment: and @KirkWoll thats the line that VS catches the CLR exception on during debugging. But of course the stack trace is gonna say the same thing

Comment: @HansKesting  yep, unfortunately:                        if (_oracleTenantSettings != null) surrounds it at an even higher level

Comment: Very sporadically? Is this a static collection that could be accessed by more than one thread? Inexplicable sporadic errors like this are often thread issues where things change between test and access.

Comment: @hatchet good thought. would a lock(new object()) around that line of code take care of it if that were the issue?

Comment: What is "_oracleTenantSettings"? How is this initialized?

Comment: @hatchet and to answer your question, yes, very much so

Comment: RE: "thats the line that VS catches the CLR exception on during debugging. But of course the stack trace is gonna say the same thing"  -- No, the top of the exception stack is not necessarily the same as the the line that visual studio is reporting the exception on. Check the stack.

Comment: @dotnetster oracletenantsettings is retrieved from cache a few lines back, but this code wouldn't even get hit if it were null.   ...unless maybe hatchet's idea is the issue

Comment: not lock(new object()) that'll jus lock on a new object

Comment: @roken No, I'm aware of that. I meant that sarcastic-angrily. Like, ***of course*** the stack is gonna say the same thing

Comment: Put a debug point here "VerifyValueInCacheOrInsert"

Comment: if you turn on break on exception, you should be able to check what exactly is null in the immediate window

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt Can you reproduce it consistently? Or is it the kind of thing where you try a fix and wait a couple of weeks to see if it breaks again.

Comment: @SandeepSinghRawat you're right. Well would locking on like the syncroot fix the issue?

Comment: Or you could just lock on `_oracleTenantSettings.OraclePlanSettings`. Be VERY careful if you plan on doing this, and thoroughly document it.

Comment: @SandeepSinghRawat not trying to be rude or anything, but if "you turn on break on exception, you should be able to check what exactly is null in the immediate window" would have fixed it, I wouldn't be asking the question

Comment: @CodingGorilla it happens quite a bit, but not at any predictable interval. Maybe 1/3 of the time the page is loaded

Comment: @dotnetster i did. when visual studio blows up on that line (or if i just debug to that line) nothing in the line is null

Comment: Try wrapping it in `lock(_oracleTenantSettings)` just to eliminate threading as an issue, but I don't think that's the cause.

Comment: if its a threading issue, yes it should fix; given that you have all proper checks in place. By the way is OraclePlanSetting a custom dictionary???

Comment: @CodingGorilla why do you not think that's it? the reason i think it may be is because I can literally load the page once - no problems. Hit refresh - no problems. hit refresh again - exception is thrown. (not necessarily every third time, lol)

Comment: @SandeepSinghRawat its a SortedList

Comment: Can you tell us how "_oracleTenantSettings" is initialized?

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt Becuase, in my experience, threading issues don't throw NRE's, especially on a collection.  I might expect a "Collection was modified" excpetion or something like that.  I might be wrong, it's just my gut instinct, especially if we're talking ASP.NET.

Comment: @dotnetster it's pulled straight from cache a few lines back. But that couldn't be the issue (assuming this isnt a thread issue), since this code will not be reached if it is null

Comment: @CodingGorilla - the reason I think thread issues could be causing NREs here is because it looks like the SortedList can have null values associated with keys. So the code checks if the key has a non-null object in the SortedList, gets an affirmative, but it's null when he tries to use it.

Comment: Can you post the the line above the code you've pasted??

Comment: @hatchet go look at my edit before you read this. maybe the issue is that after the check for _oracleTenantSettings being null, another thread comes in and hits the _oracleTenantSettings = null line...

Comment: @hatchet That's definitely a possibility, I just don't think it's likely.  It sounds like he's doing this in ASP.NET (he keeps mentioning a "page") and it's not likely (especially in a development environment) that multiple threads are accessing that code directly.  Especially if he's not the one doing the Threading (which it doesn't sound like he is).  I could be totally wrong, like I said that's just my gut feeling.

Comment: @CodingGorilla - if he has a static cache, and has configured IIS to allow multiple threads for serving client access, it would seem not unlikely at all.

Comment: make _oracleTenantSettings a local variable if this method is the only place you are using it. You dont need a lock which will cause unnecesary perf hit.

Comment: @SandeepSinghRawat i do use it elsewhere, though

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt What is _oracleCacheManager is that from the Microsoft Enterprise Library?

Comment: unless there is some very unexpected thing happening here, _oracleTenantSettings becoming null is the most likely scenario here. lock(syncObject) is the wise thing to do

Comment: @CodingGorilla no, its a custom cache manager wrapper. I didn't write it, though, so I couldn't tell you much about that one

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing the context that code lives within, it's hard to be sure. But based on the symptoms you describe, i.e. very sporadic...inexplicable...something's null that can't be... I would strongly suspect a threading issue. For example, if the collection is static and potentially accessed by multiple threads, it can happen (although it's a rare occurrence of chance timing) that a second thread modifies the collection contents between when the first thread tests if something is there and when it accesses that something.

If that's the case, you must make your code more threadsafe. You can use lock or concurrent collections to avoid this problem. To use lock, you need to use a synchronization object (not a new object created on the fly). You would also want to hunt up ALL places where that collection is accessed, and surround every one with a lock...code that just looks at the collection must use lock as well as code that modifies the collection. This is a big topic for a SO answer, so I would recommend you use this really great resource:

http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Here is how you could get NREs in this case:

```
thread 1 checks if entry exists in SortedList myList for _key="hello" 
gets true
thread 1 checks if entry for _key="hello" is non-null
gets true
thread 2 sets myList["hello"] = null
thread 1 executes myList["hello"].Something() and gets NRE.
```

Based on the edits to your post, it seems that in these lines

```
if (_oracleTenantSettings != null) {
    if (_oracleTenantSettings.OraclePlanSettings != null && _oracleTenantSettings.OraclePlanSettings.Count > 0) {
        _key = language + "_" + country + "_" + tenantId;
         if (!_oracleTenantSettings.OraclePlanSettings.ContainsKey(_key) || _oracleTenantSettings.OraclePlanSettings[_key] == null)
```

if the NRE occurs on the last line, then right after executing the first line or second line, another thread can either set `_oracleTenantSettings` or `_oracleTenantSettings.OraclePlanSettings` to null. Either of those things happening would cause the final line to throw an NRE.

The following code is not the proper way to make your code thread safe, but might serve as a quick way to see if this is indeed the case since it would make this situation (the null reference exception) less likely:

```
var oracleTS = _oracleTenantSettings;
if (oracleTS != null) {
    var planSettings = oracleTS.OraclePlanSettings;
    if ((planSettings != null) && (planSettings.Count > 0)) {
        _key = language + "_" + country + "_" + tenantId;
        if (!planSettings.ContainsKey(_key) || planSettings[_key] == null)
```

Note that the final line could still have other issues related to threading like the key being removed by another thread between the first part of the conditional and the second part, or planSettings Count changing after being tested. But if this code drastically reduces the NREs, then you have a pretty good clue what was happening, and that you should go through and properly make your code thread safe with locks where needed. To say further, a person would need to know more about what other code is doing, especially code that modifies _oracleTenantSettings.

Comment: but that would blow up on the `myList["hello"].Something()` line, no?

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt - right..you get the NRE when you try to do Something() with what is now a null value in myList.

Comment: Right, and the exception is happening at the check for `ContainsKey` or the retreival of the actual value, **not** on an attempt to use the result.  That's why I don't think it's a  threading issue.

Comment: only if somebody use dict[""].DoSomething() not if obj = dict[""];obj!=null?obj.DoSomething():DoNothing();

Comment: @CodingGorilla i think its a threading issue, but not how he thinks it is. My guess is this -- consider the following scenario: thread A checks to see if _oracleTenantSettings is null. It isn't, so it proceeds. Then thread B comes in and hits that _oracleTenantSettings = null line. Then thread A tries to access _oracleTenantSettings, thinking it couldn't possibly be null because it just checked. But it is, because thread B nullified it. Seems possible, right?

Comment: @CodingGorilla - but it still contains the key "hello"! We're talking about a key/value kind of collection. You can have a key whose associated value is null. ContainsKey will return true. But it you execute a method on the value, it will throw NRE if the value is null.

Comment: @hatchet But the exception is not happening on a line where he is doing anything with it, it's happening where he is actually checking to see if it exists.  **He's not doing anything with the value** [yet].

Comment: @hatchet but what he is/i am saying is that it isn't blowing up when a method is executed. It's blowing up when ***getting*** the value

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt I think you're misunderstanding how threading works, but some of that depends on how all of these variables are declared, and what the environment is.  I'd love to keep helping you through this problem (it's sort of a vendetta for me now =P), but I don't want to use this SO question as a discussion forum.  If you'd like, you can email me at mark at warpool.org.  If hatchet wants to join in the discussion (via email) please feel free.  If not, there are several suggestions here as to how to deal with the threading problem.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt If the `SortedList` allows `null` as a value, simply retrieving that value from the list would not cause an NRE.  It's perfectly legitimate to assign null to a variable (which is what you would be doing during the **getting**).  It's only if you attempt to do something **on** that null (where you would be expecting a reference to something else) that you get the exception.

Comment: @CodingGorilla no, I promise I understand how threading works. Its my job :) The variables in question are not local to this function. Thus multiple threads (of which there are several) hitting this code could easily modify the same object

Comment: @CodingGorilla - agree that there's enough comments and further back and forth should be offline.

Comment: @CodingGorilla right.. if _oracleTenantSettings is null, and we try to access its _oraclePlanSettings property, boom, NRE

Comment: @hatchet, care to be cc'd in the email conversation?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that there is another thread accessing the property.

A quick way to fix it would be locking on it **every time you access it** like this:

```
var oraclePlanSettings = _oracleTenantSettings.OraclePlanSettings;
lock (oraclePlanSettings)
{
    // from now on you can safely access your cached reference "oraclePlanSettings"
    if (oraclePlanSettings != null && oraclePlanSettings.Count > 0)
        _oraclePlanSettings = oraclePlanSettings[_key]; // ... blabla
}
```

Beware of deadlocks tho.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the previous answers, It's probably  a threading issue, but I have someting to add.

Here is a quick and dirty test to determine if it's threading or not.

Set up a scenerio that reproduces the error (say running it in several (10) threads in a constant loop overnight)

Apply this attribute to your class

[Synchronization]

Your Class must inherit from ContextBoundObject.

That forces all the instances of the class to run on a single thread (way slower).

Re run your test.

If your problem goes away, you have a threading issue. If speed is a concern, you need to go back and do all the locking around the code that touches that object. If you convert everything to use properties for the objects in question you can just lock the getter and setter.

If the quick and dirty test fails to fix the issue, it's probabaly something else. For instance if you're using unsafe code or unsafe dlls (ie stuff written in non .Net c++), it might be a memory corruption problem.

Hope this helps.

Here is more detail on the attribute, including inheriting from ContextBoundObject.

[Ms Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.contexts.synchronizationattribute.aspx)

Code sample:

```
// Context-bound type with the Synchronization context attribute.
[Synchronization()]
public class SampleSynchronized : ContextBoundObject {

    // A method that does some work, and returns the square of the given number.
    public int Square(int i)  {

        Console.Write("The hash of the thread executing ");
        Console.WriteLine("SampleSynchronized.Square is: {0}", 
                             Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode());
        return i*i;
    }
}
```

Comment: great answer - I'll look into this shortly

Comment: Please be aware, If you're new to it, doing all the "lock" stuff is non trivial. you have to put a lock around everysingle bit of code that uses the resource in question.. If you miss even one, you can still get the "thread racing condition". The more encapsulated, and better seperation of concerns you have, the easier this is. Another place where good design pays off and bad design punishes :)

Comment: It's worth noting that SynchronizationAttribute covers instance fields and instance methods, but not static fields and static methods. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8chs7ft%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Nice! Didn't know that is does not sychronize global fields either. Good catch!

Answer (score -1):

### Update

I am proposing that somewhere in the code the Equality operator or the == has been overloaded on one of the related objects and the failure occurs when either null is not be checked for properly (or fails) or something is returned as equal when it is not.

Check for all operator overloads on == for any class object being used in this situation and rectify..

### Original

Change the logic to this, for you want to first check for no key...THEN..do the check when there is a valid key but (*and*) its value is null:

```
 if ((_oracleTenantSettings.OraclePlanSettings.ContainsKey(_key) == false) || 
     ((_oracleTenantSettings.OraclePlanSettings.ContainsKey(_key)) && 
       _oracleTenantSettings.OraclePlanSettings[_key] == null)))
```

Its actually expected if you think through the logic flow of the original statements why it intermittently fails. :-)

**EDIT**:
Let me explain, Follow this logic by steps

1. In the original if clause when it evaluates the (!ContainsKey(_key)) means that when the key is NOT there (true) it gets changed to FALSE.
2. Then the Or kicks in because of False in #1. It evaluates the OraclePlanSettings[_key] *BUT* the key is not there right?
3. So it executes code to check on null for *an invalid key* and throws an exception.

Only by breaking out the logic as I have shown, will the excpetion not be thrown.

Comment: Not sure i get this either. if the first side of the if passes (meaning it does have the key), then checking for the value in the second half of the if will always work -- no need to verify that the key exists

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt There are two circumstances in which the code needs to report that the TenantObjectDoesNotExist is missing. 

The first is when plan settings has no key (ContainsKey == false). 

The second situation is when there is a valid key (ContainsKey == true) AND the value contained is null. 

By -or- ing those two seperate conditions toghether, it gives us the logic to report TenantObjectDoesNotExist in the body of the if.

Comment: right, so there are two scenarios: if ContainsKey==false, the second half of the if isn't executed. If it isn't false, then it's true, meaning (_oracleTenantSettings.OraclePlanSettings.ContainsKey(_key)) is true and thus checking for that AND _oracleTenantSettings.OraclePlanSettings[_key] == null gets the same result as just checking for _oracleTenantSettings.OraclePlanSettings[_key] == null

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt No wait...I think I must have misinterpreted it. DOH!

Comment: @OmegaMan but think about it like this. the second half of the IF statement will NEVER be executed unless ContainsKey == true. So, if  The second half is executed, ContainsKey == true. So, replacing ContainsKey with true, we get: if ((_oracleTenantSettings.OraclePlanSettings.ContainsKey(_key) == false) || 
     (TRUE && 
       _oracleTenantSettings.OraclePlanSettings[_key] == null)) and by boolean logic, TRUE && bool == bool.

Comment: @OmegaMan its a really easy thing to misinterpret :P thanks for the help anyway

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt sorry to lead you down the wrong path. My bad.

Comment: @OmegaMan well hey, on the bright side, you helped re-tone my boolean logic skills!

Comment: And anytime I get to correct a c# MVP is a good thing in my book! :)

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt I am the sort of person who welcomes correction. For its better to fail than to never had tried. :-)

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt I ran into a situation and thought it may apply to your situation; I wrote it up as an update.